# Spring Forces in D3.js Force directed layout?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph-visualization, graph-layout, force-layout

The description of this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045 (find image below), states that it is "A physical simulation of charged particles and springs places related characters in closer proximity."

[image]

I was just curious which part of that code (on that same page) implements or defines the spring forces, especially based on related characters?

I ask this because i was under the impression that D3.js does not implement spring forces for the Force directed layouts, as mentioned in its API documentation:

"Links are not implemented as "spring forces", as in common in other force-directed layouts, but as weak geometric constraints." -https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-linkDistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In D3 force-directed layout, the spring forces are defined using the `gravity` method that defaults to `0.1` if not set.

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4sq4F/) of the same example you mentioned with gravity set to `0.9`.

The "weak geometric constraints" mentioned in the `linkDistance` documentation are talked about further [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-gravity).

> *"gravity is implemented as a weak geometric constraint similar to a virtual spring connecting each node to the center of the layout's
>   size. "*

Comment: ah i c... so there are still no spring-forces as such, but the gravitational force is a "spring" like force. thanks a ton!